# Difference between address.call.value().gas()() and address.call{value: amount}("")

Tags: solidity

I have read some article saying it's recommended to use `address.call.value().gas()()` to send ethers, however, some saying call.value is a very low-level function and should only be used as the last resort as it breaks the type-safety of Solidity.

It seems that `address.call{value: amount}("")` is a newer way to send ethers but how is it different from `.call.value`?

Answer (score 1):

There is not difference between `address.call.value().gas()()` and `address.call{value: amount}("")` besides the difference in syntax.

With [Solidity 0.6.4](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.6.4) the notation `.value().gas()` was deprecated.

There was a longer discussion on this syntax on Github: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2136#issuecomment-559196297 and here is the PR when the new syntax was implemented: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/pull/8177